# From Dictionary, how to output specific columns to CSV

Tags: python, csv

Using this [example](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch06.html#_discussion_94)  for a CSV dictreader, how can you output specific columns and/or a different order to a CSV?

```
import csv
headers = ['Symbol', 'Price', 'Date', 'Time', 'Change', 'Volume']
rows = [{'Symbol':'AA', 'Price':39.48, 'Date':'6/11/2007',
          'Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.18, 'Volume':181800},
        {'Symbol':'AIG', 'Price': 71.38, 'Date':'6/11/2007',
          'Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.15, 'Volume': 195500},
        {'Symbol':'AXP', 'Price': 62.58, 'Date':'6/11/2007',
          'Time':'9:36am', 'Change':-0.46, 'Volume': 935000},
        ]

with open('stocks.csv','w') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
    f_csv.writeheader()
    f_csv.writerows(rows)
```

How could I output the volume, then the date (columns are re-ordered and 2 columns not outputted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `extrasaction` parameter to the [`DictWriter` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
with open('stocks.csv','w') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, ['Volume','Date'], extrasaction='ignore')
    f_csv.writeheader()
    f_csv.writerows(rows)
```

Result:

```
Volume,Date
181800,6/11/2007
195500,6/11/2007
935000,6/11/2007
```

Comment: Wow, I've used `DictWriter` a lot and have never known about this - I always just do a generator of dict comprehensions before I pass it to `writerows`. Well done!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not super familiar with dictwriter but you could build a list of dictionaries with just the fields you want

```
myfields = ['Volume', 'Date']
myrows = []
for row in rows:
    myrow = {}
    for field in myfields:
        myrow[field] = row.get(field)
    myrows.append(myrow)
f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, myfields)
f_csv.writeheader()
f_csv.writerows(myrows)
```

Comment: Rob's answer is cleaner and better utilizes the built-in functionality of dictwriter. I was a little too slow in answering!